# Hide calculated column in view but still have it run its code

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have a task list with a calculated column that includes some code to change the background color of the list items based on their priority value, see below

[image]

Is there a way to hide the calculated column from the view but still have it run its code, if I remove the column from the view then obviously it won't run the code to color the list

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
=[Priority] 
&"<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{" 
&"var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode}"
&"row.style.backgroundColor='#" 
&CHOOSE( RIGHT( LEFT( [Priority] , 2) , 1) , "F78181" , "BCF5A9" , "F3F781" , "81B1F8") 
&"'}"">"
```

Comment: Why not use JSLink to do this? You don't need to show the calculated column then.

Comment: What is the code you have now in your Calculated Column? I have plenty of examples available I can add to your code.

Comment: @DannyEngelman the current code I have is =[Priority] &"<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif"" onload=""{" &"var row=this;while(row.tagName!='TR'){row=row.parentNode}" &"row.style.backgroundColor='#" &CHOOSE( RIGHT( LEFT( [Priority] , 2) , 1) , "F78181" , "BCF5A9" , "F3F781" , "81B1F8") &"'}"">" do you have an example that I could add to this to hide the calculated column, I need to keep the original priority column as this is a drop down list that can be edited in quick edit mode

Comment: You want this on a page with ONE List View webpart?

Comment: @DannyEngelman Not sure what you mean, this list is a task list that contains data for project tasks, it is the only list/web part on the page, the idea is that there is a priority column so the task can be set high, normal or low and color coordinated accordingly, so I still need to keep the original Priority column as this will be changed/updated but obviously need the CC as well for the code

Answer (score 1):

Why not exclude the original `Priority1` Column from the list, and wrap your Calculated Column in

```
<div style="text-align:left">
 ...
</div>
```

*Now that is something CSR can **not** do..

With CSR You need the value displayed in the View in order to work with it.*

You loose the fance sorting and filtering, so I usually display another less meaningfull column in the Calculated Column

You can also leave it blank, and/or even add code to hide the whole column (after it executed)

### If you are moving to CSR - Client Side Rendering

Then at least write a function as generic as possible

- no fieldname dependency
- no language dependency
- no external Image file dependencies

  ```
  function priorityFieldTemplate(ctx) {
      var fieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name],
          colorIndex=fieldValue.match(/(\d+)/g),//(extract x from '(x) Label'
          color=['none','red','orange','green','brown'][colorIndex],
          circleSize=15,
          H="<svg height={0} width={0}><circle cx={1} cy={1} r={1} fill='{2}'/></svg>";
      return String.format( H , circleSize, circleSize/2, color);
  }
  ```

ICSR

Comment: With my script above I still can sort and filter by the status column... updated my answer with the picture of sorting and filtering

Comment: Nice. Where will you wrap this calculated column btw?

Comment: Because the CC is datatype=Number it is right-aligned, so to get it aligned to the left again add a DIV to you exisiting code. You could also add JS code ``this.parentNode.style.textAlign='left';

Answer (score 0):

I had similar task. I had to show multiline text field/column shorten. I did that with additional column that was calculated field and I hid it with help of javascript.
Add script webpart page and in it just hide that class and that is all.

Answer (score 0):

As Akhoy says, I personally recommend js-link.

Here are two links where you should see how it is done:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd

and a blog post from myself (Statuscolumn changed to traffic light icons):

https://blog.afrait.com/traffic-light-column-in-custom-list-en/

Here the script, tried to match your requirements a little:

```
<script>    
(function () {
        var statusFieldCtx = {};


        statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
        statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
            "Priority1": {
                "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
            }
        };

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
            statusFieldCtx
            );
    })();

    function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {

        var _statusValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Priority1;

         if (_statusValue == '(1) High')
         {
             return "<img src='http://sp13/teams/PublishingImages/Ampel/red.png'/>";
         }

         if (_statusValue == '(2) Normal')
         {
             return "<img src='http://sp13/teams/PublishingImages/Ampel/yellow.png'/>";
         } 

         if (_statusValue == '(3) Low')
         {
             return "<img src='http://sp13/teams/PublishingImages/Ampel/green.png'/>";
         }   

         if (_statusValue == '(4) Done')
         {
         return "<img src='http://sp13/teams/PublishingImages/Ampel/brown.png'/>";
         } 

    }
</script>
```

Maybe you will decide to choose js-link in the future. Also you can still sort and filter by the status column. See here:

[image]